# How to unify 3 different SELECT queries, so they can be used to pull 10 values each from 3 different categories for INSERTing into one temp table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-insert

There is a `latest_comments` table, that gets rewritten every N minutes. The contents are pulled from `posts` and `comments` tables and get merged together. There are **3 different categories** (red, green, blue), where **10 latest comments from each category** should be represented in the `latest_comments`.

**Without unifying / merging the query looks like:**

```
INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'red'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;

INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'green'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;

INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'blue'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

**How to merge all 3 SELECT queries, so only 1 INSERT query can be used, while keeping it as optimised as possible in regards of performance?**

I have tried all I could find and all I could try to come up with my logic. None of them have worked and I think 3 separate INSERT queries are slowing the function down. What I wish would work for example:

```
INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
(SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'red'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10),

(SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'green'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10),

(SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'blue'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10);
```

Comment: look at `UNION`

Comment: or, do p.category IN ('red', 'green', 'blue') instead of 3 different SELECTS

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya But I want 10 from each. IN obviously works, but it wont get me 10 each from 3 different categories.

Comment: Please check my UNION ALL solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

```
INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)

(SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'red'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'green'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT
p.id AS `post_id`,
c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
c.date AS `date`,
c.comment AS `comment`,
p.category AS `category`
FROM `comments` AS c
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
ON c.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.category = 'blue'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10)
```

Comment: So basically, SQL finds a syntax error in the `(` after INSERT query. That can be solved by adding VALUES at the end of INSERT. But it still says syntax error with UNION ALL.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas I dont think you need `VALUES` clause, check the syntax at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: So yeah, VALUES caused an error. But the one ( after INSERT caused syntax error. Overall however, separating each SELECT with () was critical and there for I think this answer deserves the accept, if you edit the () wrap out from around the SELECTS.

Comment: Side question: If only doing SELECT part without INSERT, how to randomise the output?

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas check [ORDER BY RAND()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx)

Comment: Yes of course, but what is the syntax on how to merge the 3 queries together to have order by rand() at the end?

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas yes, you can do ORDER BY RAND() at the end for the UNION result

Comment: While the mysql panel gives errors in the quick SQL command view, it goes trough and works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you want 10 rows form eacj query you could use UNION ALL

```
        INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
        (SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p ON c.post_id = p.id
        WHERE p.category = 'red'
        ORDER BY c.date DESC
        LIMIT 0, 10)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
        ON c.post_id = p.id WHERE p.category = 'green'
        ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 )
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        LEFT JOIN `posts` AS p
        ON c.post_id = p.id WHERE p.category = 'blue'
        ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10)
```

Anyway you are using  left join table column `WHERE p.category = 'blue'` in where  clause  this work as an inner  join

```
        INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
        (SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        INNER JOIN `posts` AS p ON c.post_id = p.id and p.category = 'red'
        ORDER BY c.date DESC
        LIMIT 0, 10)

        UNION ALL
        (SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        INNER JOIN `posts` AS p ON c.post_id = p.id AND p.category = 'green'
        ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        INNER JOIN `posts` AS p ON c.post_id = p.id AND p.category = 'blue'
        ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10);
```

or if you just need  30 rows  you could use a IN clause

```
        INSERT INTO `latest_comments` (`post_id`, `comment_id`, `date`, `comment`, `category`)
        SELECT
            p.id AS `post_id`,
            c.post_id AS `comment_id`,
            c.date AS `date`,
            c.comment AS `comment`,
            p.category AS `category`
        FROM `comments` AS c
        INNER JOIN `posts` AS p ON c.post_id = p.id and p.category IN ( 'red', 'green', 'blue')
        ORDER BY c.date DESC
        LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: Plus 1 for INNER JOIN

Comment: I get syntax error in regards to UNION ALL. And in regards of IN clause, I need 10 comments from each category not 30 comments randomly from every category. This would mean that one category has 15, other 3 and last 2 comments.

Comment: answer updted  .. removed  wron ; ath the end of each select

Comment: The query for IN clause is not able to retrive 10 for each category  .. if you need  10 for each category  .. you can use select ....union all

Comment: @scaisEdge Right now `SELECT `id` FROM `posts` WHERE `category` = 'blue' LIMIT 0, 10

UNION ALL

SELECT `id` FROM `posts` WHERE `category` = 'green' LIMIT 0, 10` gives me already syntax error.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas  .  i have added () around select but .. but why in your code the blue select come before gree .. my query is first gree and the blue .. have you changed somethings?   .. try also the inner join version

Comment: Ok the problem was, that the SELECT's need to be separated with () brackets each. There for I think its fair, that Madhur's answer gets the check. Thank you anyways for the answer.

Comment: correct because you have separated  order by and limit and for this each query must be isolated ..